# How to fix bunch of no reverse math errors in Django

Tags: python, django

I read everything about no reverse match error but nothings changed. My  task is "In the view related to the list of posts that are filtered, how to filter the posts based on the time that is considered for publication. This filter should be such that it takes the time considered for the published_date section, and compares it with the current time.  If it is past the current time, it should be displayed and otherwise not." and "In the view related to displaying a single post, insert a function that every time the view related to each post is called, one unit will be added to the counted_view attribute of that post."

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from blog.views import *

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', blog_view, name='index'),
    path('single/<int:pid>', blog_single, name='single')
] 


# views.py 

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import blog_Post
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your views here.

def blog_view(request, pid):
    posts = blog_Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now(), status=1, pk=pid)
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, "blog/blog-home.html",context)

def blog_single(request, pid):
    
    
    blog_object = get_object_or_404(blog_Post, pk=pid)
    blog_object.counted_views += 1
    blog_object.save()
    
        
return render(request, "blog/blog-single.html", {'posts':blog_object})]

base.html

<li><a href="{% url 'blog:index'   %}">Blog Home</a></li          

 <li><a href="{% url 'blog:single' pid=post.id %}">Blog Single</a></li>
```

Comment: Please consider rewording your question and use punctuations.

Comment: What does the error message actually say?

Comment: it says "Reverse for 'single' with keyword arguments '{'pid': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/single/(?P<pid>[0-9]+)\\Z']"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/) as `posts = blog_Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now(), status=1, pk=pid)`, and although there may be only ONE, it is still a Queryset, which needs to be evaluated.  Something like:

```py
{% for p in post %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'blog:single' pid=p.id %}">Blog Single</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Or, you can use `post = blog_Post.objects.get(published_date__lte=timezone.now(), status=1, pk=pid)`, which will return ONE instance, although I would make sure that that object actaully exists, so maybe do

```
post = blog_Post.objects.get_object_or_404(published_date__lte=timezone.now(), status=1, pk=pid)
```

*bottom line**
The line

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:single' pid=post.id %}">
```

most likely has `post.id` as none, which is what is causing the error.